# Handler method name in SpringAmqp interceptors

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I use spring amqp with multi-method listeners, like this:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = PLATFORM_COMMAND_QUEUE)
@Component
public class PlatformListener {

    @RabbitHandler
    public Response<GetAllPlatformsResponse> getAllPlatforms(GetAllPlatforms command) {
        ...
        return Response.ok(GetAllPlatformsResponse.create(allPlatforms));
    }

    @RabbitHandler
    public Response<PlatformResponse> getPlatform(GetPlatformCommand command) {
        ...        
        return Response.ok(platformService.getPlatform(command));
    }
}
```

And I wand add specific header with handler name (getAllPlatforms, getPlatform) for all response messages. For that, i try add setAfterReceivePostProcessors and setBeforeSendReplyPostProcessors, but they do not provide any information about handler methods.

```
 factory.setBeforeSendReplyPostProcessors(message -> {
     Method targetMethod = message.getMessageProperties().getTargetMethod();
     assert targetMethod == null;
     return message;
 });
```

How can i get method name and add it to reply message header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not currently possible; as the javadocs state, that property is only populated for method-level `@RabbitListener`.

```
/**
 * The target method when using a method-level {@code @RabbitListener}.
 * @return the method.
 * @since 1.6
 */
public Method getTargetMethod() {
    return this.targetMethod;
}
```

Given some changes to the architecture over the years, I think it should now be possible to populate this also for class-level listeners. Please [open a new feature suggestion](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues) and I'll take a look at adding it.

Comment: I opened [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/1133).

Comment: Thank you. We will wait release.